# How to un-encrypt a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, utf-8, solver, knapsack-problem

Here is the the format of encription

The password structure is as follows:
`<section1>-<section2>-<section3>-<section4>-<section5>`

### Section 1

The first name length added to the last name length.
i.e. `'David Lindley' = 5 + 7 = 12`

### Section 2

The captialised last letter of the first name
i.e. `'David Lindley' = 'D'`

### Section 3

The lowercasefirst character of the last name
i.e. `'David Lindley' = 'l'`

### Section 4

The total number of vowels (a, e, i, o, u) in the full name
i.e. `'David Lindley' = 4`

### Section 5

A hash of the name based on the following:

1. Any duplicate characters removed
   i.e. `'David Lindley' = 'Davi Lney'`
2. Remove any blank spaces from step 1
   i.e. `'Davi Lney' = 'DaviLney'`
3. Replace every character from step 2 with its lowercase UTF-8/16 character code
   i.e. `'DaviLney' = [100, 97, 118, 105, 108, 110, 101, 121]`
4. The output from step 3 added together:
   i.e. `100 + 97 + 118 + 105 + 108 + 110 + 101 + 121 = 860`
   The output from step 4 is the code for Section 5

## Example password

`'David Lindley' = '12-D-l-4-860'`

## Explained

The first number is there first name and last name added together

second letter is there first capital letter

third letter is there first lowercase letter

final number is following the space removal and duplicate letters, then adding the UTF-8/16 character code matching each letter

So my questions is how would i write a function that would take a encrypted string and then un-encrypt it to get there regular name

Comment: You can't. There's many non-reversible steps (i.e. steps that irrecoverably discard information) in there. You could maybe generate a few guesses if you had a dictionary (i.e. a list of all possible first and last names) or have some other source of information, but if the input can be any arbitrary string, then you just discard way to much information. This isn't "encryption" as much as it's a complicated way to hash something that exposes more details about the input than most other hashes (but still not enough to reconstruct the input).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in cryptography but I don't think you can since there is a loss of information. A reverse algorithm would have to compute an enormous amount of combinations using a dictionary of names, by encrypting them and checking them against your encrypted string. Basically brute forcing it.

You could then stop at the first match or maybe output a list of matches.

If you don't **have to** use this method and just need to encrypt/decrypt simple strings, I suggest you take to look at [symmetric encryption](https://medium.com/@spatocode/symmetric-encryption-in-javascript-bcb5fd14c273)